# perl split string into 2d array

Tags: perl, arrays, multidimensional-array, printing, auto-populate

Okay .. this works ...

```
sub getApSrvs
{
my %apsrv;
my $cluster;

  foreach $cluster (getClusters())
  {
  $apsrv{$cluster} = [split('\s+', `/$cluster/bin/gethosts -t app|sort -u`)];
  }
return %apsrv;
}
```

... now how in the ham sandwich do I get this to print like so **$cluster --> $hostname**

okay I added :

```
my %apsrv = getApSrvs();
for my $cluster (keys %apsrv) {
print "$cluster -> $apsrv{$cluster}\n";
}
```

and I get ...

> qboc22 -> ARRAY(0x9111618)
>
> qboc5 -> ARRAY(0x9111504)
>
> qboc32 -> ARRAY(0x90e20cc)
>
> qboc28 -> ARRAY(0x90e1d28)
>
> qboc30 -> ARRAY(0x90e1f38)
>
> qboc23 -> ARRAY(0x9111540)
>
> qboc27 -> ARRAY(0x911181c)
>
> qboc29 -> ARRAY(0x91115ac)
>
> qbo -> ARRAY(0x90e2294)

Comment: And what has your problem been that you need help with?

Comment: There is no answer without a specific question -- how is your code not working? What does the data look like that is being parsed by `split`?

Comment: `split` returns an array, so you'll want to assign a reference to the array:  `$apsrv{$cluster} = [ split(...) ]`. Otherwise I have no idea what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

$apsrv{$cluster} is a reference to an array, so if you want to print the contents of it you can do :

```
my %apsrv = getApSrvs();
for my $cluster (keys %apsrv) {
    print "$cluster -> ", join(', ', @$apsrv{$cluster}), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my %apsrv = getApSrvs();
for my $cluster (keys %apsrv) {
    print "$cluster -> $apsrv{$cluster}\n";
}
```

You will want to sort the keys (`sort keys %apsrv`) before printing if the order is important.